# Percentage change from previous row when multiple rows have the same date?

Tags: mysql, sql, function, date, datetime

I have a query that calculates ratios and returns them for each hour and server on a given day:

```
SELECT a.day, 
       a.hour, 
       Sum(a.gemspurchased), 
       Sum(b.gems), 
       Sum(b.shadowgems), 
       ( Sum(b.gems) / Sum(a.gemspurchased) )       AS GemRatio, 
       ( Sum(b.shadowgems) / Sum(a.gemspurchased) ) AS ShadowGemRatio 
FROM   (SELECT Date(Date_sub(createddate, INTERVAL 7 hour)) AS day, 
               Hour(Date_sub(createddate, INTERVAL 7 hour)) AS hour, 
               serverid, 
               Sum(gems)                                    AS GemsPurchased 
        FROM   dollartransactions 
        WHERE  Date(Date_sub(createddate, INTERVAL 7 hour)) BETWEEN 
               Curdate() - INTERVAL 14 day AND Curdate() 
        GROUP  BY 1, 
                  2, 
                  3) a, 
       /*Gems recorded from DollarTransactions Table after purchasing gem package*/ 
       (SELECT Date(Date_sub(createddate, INTERVAL 7 hour)) AS day, 
               Hour(Date_sub(createddate, INTERVAL 7 hour)) AS hour, 
               serverid, 
               Sum(acceptedamount)                          AS Gems, 
               Sum(acceptedshadowamount)                    AS ShadowGems 
        FROM   gemtransactions 
        WHERE  Date(Date_sub(createddate, INTERVAL 7 hour)) BETWEEN 
                       Curdate() - INTERVAL 14 day AND Curdate() 
               AND transactiontype IN ( 990, 2 ) 
               AND fullfilled = 1 
               AND gemtransactionid >= 130000000 
        GROUP  BY 1, 
                  2, 
                  3) b 
/*Gems & Shadow Gems spent, recorded from GemTransactions Table */ 
WHERE  a.day = b.day 
       AND a.serverid = b.serverid 
GROUP  BY 1, 
          2
```

This code returns the component parts of the ratios, as well as the ratios themselves (which are sometimes null):

```
day       hour  sum(a.GemsPurchased)    sum(b.Gems) sum(b.ShadowGems)   GemRatio ShadowGemRatio
9/5/2014    0   472875                   465499      60766              0.9844    0.1285
9/5/2014    1   350960                   371092      45408              1.0574    0.1294
9/5/2014    2   472985                   509618      58329              1.0775    0.1233
9/5/2014    3   1023905                  629310      71017              0.6146    0.0694
9/5/2014    4   1273170                  628697      74896              0.4938    0.0588
9/5/2014    5   998920                   637709      64145              0.6384    0.0642
9/5/2014    6   876470                   651451      68977              0.7433    0.0787
9/5/2014    7   669100                   667217      81599              0.9972    0.122
```

What I'd like to do is create an 8th and 9th column which calculate the % change from previous row for both GemRatio and ShadowGemRatio. I've seen other threads here on how to do this for specific queries, but I couldn't get it to work for my particular MySQL query...

Answer (score 0):

Ok first create a view for that query. Let's call it v1:

> CREATE VIEW v1 AS SELECT **YOUR QUERY HERE**;

Now here is the query to have the ratios. I assumed a day has 24 hours. The first row ratio change will be zero.

```
select now.*,
CASE 
  WHEN yesterday.gemRatio is null THEN 0
  ELSE 100*(now.gemRatio-yesterday.gemRatio)/yesterday.gemRatio
END as gemChange,
CASE 
  WHEN yesterday.ShadowGemRatio is null THEN 0
  ELSE 100*(now.ShadowGemRatio-yesterday.ShadowGemRatio)/yesterday.ShadowGemRatio
END as shadowGemChange
from v1 now left outer join v1 yesterday on 
((now.day = yesterday.day && now.hour = yesterday.hour+1) || 
(DATEDIFF(now.day,yesterday.day) = 1  && now.hour = 0 && yesterday.hour=23))
```